# Get screen size (in pixels) for secondary monitor

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to get the screen size in pixels for a secondary monitor using Matlab? get(0,'ScreenSize') seems to only recognize the screen on the main monitor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using get(0,'[MonitorPositions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rootobject_props.html)') instead. It returns the width and height of primary and secondary monitors, in pixels.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and got this:

           1           1        1280        1024
       -1919        -175           0        1024
To get the screen size of the secondary monitor I did this:

dual=get(0,'MonitorPositions');
scrsz = [(dual(2,3)-dual(2,1)),(dual(2,4)-dual(2,2))];

Comment: On a Mac (macOS 10.12) I had a problem where `get(0,'MonitorPositions');` wouldn't find both displays. Restarting the computer with both displays plugged in solved the issue. Just for posterity.